# I need help refactoring my two JS functions into one versatile function in my code (JS array.reduce)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

My goal is to find the *"total number of something"* within an array.

e.g. each object within this array **"arrayOfBikes"** has a **"free"** property, and I want to find the total value of **"free"**.

I'm trying to minimize the amount of code I have written.

Is it possible to write a function that takes an array and an item to count being either (free or bikes) I have been trying to implement it below but I ran into bugs *"getTotalNumberOfBikes()"*

```
var arrayOfBikes = [
{name: "blackhall", lat: 53.3488, lng: -6.281637, free: 22, bikes: 8},
{name: "mbrown", lat: 53.341645, lng: -6.29719, free: 14, bikes: 8},
{name: "grant street", lat: 53.334123, lng: -6.265436, free: 3, bikes: 27},
{name: "gratstreet", lat: 53.339629, lng: -6.243778, free: 19, bikes: 4},
{name: "hardstreet", lat: 53.355473, lng: -6.264423, free: 14, bikes: 2}
];


function getTotalNumberOfFreeBikes(_array){

  let arrayOfFreeBikes = [];

  _array.forEach(function(element){
    arrayOfFreeBikes.push(element.free);
  });

  return arrayOfFreeBikes.reduce(function(_previousValue, _currentValue){
    return _previousValue + _currentValue;
  }, 0);

}

function getTotalNumberOfBikes(_array){

   let arrayOfBikes = [];

   _array.forEach(function(element){
     arrayOfBikes.push(element.bikes);
   });

   return arrayOfBikes.reduce(function(_previousValue, _currentValue){
     return _previousValue + _currentValue;
   }, 0);

}//getTotalNumberOfBikes


document.getElementById('freeBikes').innerHTML = 'Total free bikes : ' + getTotalNumberOfFreeBikes(arrayOfBikes);
document.getElementById('Bikes').innerHTML = 'Total bikes : ' + getTotalNumberOfBikes(arrayOfBikes);


function getTotalNumberOfBikes(_array, _item){

   let arrayOfBikes = [], itemToCount = _array._item;

   _array.forEach(function(element){
     arrayOfBikes.push(itemToCount);
   });

   return arrayOfBikes.reduce(function(_previousValue, _currentValue){
     return _previousValue + _currentValue;
   }, 0);

}//getTotalNumberOfBikes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduce is perfect for this:

```
var count = arrayOfBikes.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.free, 0)
```

If you want to generalize it you can do something like this:

```
function getCountOf(array, prop) {
    return array.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr[prop], 0)
}

console.log(getCountOf(arrayOfBikes, 'free'))
// 72
console.log(getCountOf(arrayOfBikes, 'bikes'))
// 49
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark_M I really appreciate this, your code looks awesome !!!